# How to type a command more than 257 characters in putty?

Tags: putty

Putty doesn't allow typing more than 257 characters. I have searched the terminal settings, there is no option to set the maximum command length.

Comment: How do you figure this would be a limitation of putty? I have no problem typing commands of >2000 characters in putty. So we need more information. Linux version you are connected to and shell you're using (bash, csh, etc.). What is the output of your `getconf ARG_MAX`?

Comment: In addition to @Rik's comment, PuTTY has no concept of whether you are typing a command (into a shell), or simply text (into an editor, say). Do you have the same problem when typing into an editor? If you don't, then it is even more unlikely to be related to PuTTY specifically.

Answer (score 2):

> **How to type a command more than 257 characters in putty?**

You can do this by typing in 257 characters and then pressing any key on your keyboard that corresponds to a printable character†.

If your server's command-shell or operating system ignores this, you can address this by reconfiguring or replacing the offending software.

Details depend on what shell and operating system you use.

```
$ uname -s -r
Linux 2.6.18-274.3.1.el5
$ getconf ARG_MAX
131072
```

One thing that can trip you up on some operating systems is wildcard expansion. For example:

```
$ csh
1% ls *
Arguments too long.
```

when this occurs I switch to a better shell.

---

There's some good advice [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/argument-list-too-long-error-solution/) - essentially

> You have following option to get around these limitations:
>
> Use `find` or `xargs` command
>   Use shell `for` / `while` loop

---

† The intro to my answer may seem a bit flippant but the important point here is that a very important part about troubleshooting is *challenging your assumptions*. Another important point about stackexchange sites is that questions need answers. Not least so that they disappear from the list of unanswered questions. Comments help the questioner improve their question but, unless they are acted on, they don't always move things along the road to closure. I've made this community wiki to make it clear I'm not just harvesting reputation points.

<sub>*‘I thought dwarfs loved gold,’ said Angua. ‘They just say that to get it into bed.’ replied Cheery.*</sub>

Comment: Wait wait wait wait wait...did you just answer "I can't type more then 257 characters" with "well, type more then 257 characters"?

Comment: @Bobby: No, I answered a different question, the one I quoted :-)

Answer (score -1):

You are probably using csh shell.  Try switching to bash by entering the command

```
 bash
```

then running your long command.

Comment: What makes you think that the C Shell has a 257 character line length limit?

Comment: Experience.  When I'm using putty csh shell on putty and I enter a long command, putty complains that the command is too long.  When I switch to bash, I can enter a command that is as long as I want.

Comment: Your conclusions and descriptions are bogus.  For starters, PuTTY doesn't know what is a command and what isn't, as explained earlier in this very question, so **it** did not complain to you about anything.  And one can demonstrably **type 258 or more characters** at the C Shell prompt.  I just did, for kicks.